# Batch add LoadBalancers to AutoScaling Groups with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

We have an AWS CloudFormation template that creates a single AutoScaling group and then adds LoadBalancers to it. Unfortunately there is a limit to how many LoadBalancers you can add at any  one time. Ten to be precise. Does anybody know if it is possible to batch add the LoadBalancers?
We have to stick with CloudFormation as it is supplied by the vendor of the Market Place AMI we are using, although we can tweak it slightly.

Comment: Where is that limit documented? Is it a per account limit or a stack/template limit? I am not aware of a limit of 10. AWS allows 20 per *region*

Comment: Can you maybe combine some of those load balancers into a single Application Load Balancer?

Comment: The limitation is documented on the AutoScaling service limits page. It's not in the main table as it's not a limit you can increase.
We can't use application load balancers as we are stuck with what the vendor chooses to use in the CloudFormation template.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Auto Scaling Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-account-limits.html) does limit ASG attach or detach to at most 10 at a time. This is the source of that limit.

If you can, you would break the template into two parts: Part 1 would create only the ASG, and Part 2 would add 10 ELB at one time. Part 1 would export the ID of the ASG, which would be referenced in Part 2.

Then you you would need to write a script that would call the Part 2 template as many times as you like, while looping/waiting for the first 10 attachments to complete.

With this approach you could add up to the max of 50 ELBs per ASG.